# Error deploying ASP.NET website on Azure WebApp with GitHub

Tags: asp.net, azure, github, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 with every needed extensions to work and deploy on Azure.

I made a project ASP.NET 5 website (the template given by visual studio by default) and I can publish it from Visual Studio to Azure but when I link my Github repository to my WebApp on Azure and it tries to deploy it I get an error message:

[image: Error message]

-Tried to deploy it on an already deployed website from GitHub => Fail
-Tried to deploy it on an empty WebApp from GitHub => Fail too

It doesn't make sense to me. Why can it deploy perfectly from Visual Studio but cannot from GitHub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me try to answer your question

> "Why can it deploy perfectly from Visual Studio but cannot from GitHub ?"

when deploy from visual studio, visual studio use WebDeploy technology which copy all the binary from your machine onto your website that run on Azure App Services.

when you deployment from Github via continuous deployment, behind the scenes, [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) (engine driving your deployment) will clone a copy of your repository next to your site. Which will use some more disk space of yours.

from the error message, you are running out of disk space. So you will either free up some space yourself (e.g go to https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, remove some unused file) or upgrade to a better plan https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

Comment: Okay, I tried indeed to upgrade (Because my plan had only 1GB free space disk at the beginning) and indeed when you upgrade (I upgraded to Basic) you can fully deploy without any issues on Azure.